# Async/Await funcion only returning the last result instead all the results desired in a for

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I've this code

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (addresses.includes(jsonResponse[i].address)){
            console.log(jsonResponse[i].address + " --> " +jsonResponse[i].balance)
            var testbalance = new Balance({address: jsonResponse[i].address, balance: Math.round(Number(jsonResponse[i].balance))}) //saves the top10 richlist addresses


            function saveBalance(){  
                return testbalance.save();
            }


        }
    }


    async function sendData() {
        const data = await saveBalance(); //this only gets the last result of the for, but i need it to get all the results [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] , but it only saves the [9]
        Balance.find({}, function(err, data){
            bot.sendMessage(groupId, JSON.stringify(data)) 
          });
    }

    sendData();
```

The for basically reads an api, and saves it in my database (mongoose) , then theres a call to a function that reads all the saved data and sends it to telegram (its a telegram bot)

Comment: You got to build up that Array of results and return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to populate an array with the data as suggested , and then used mongoose model.create in order to upload it.

Finally managed to make it async

```
var testbalance = [];
    //populates testbalance array in order to upload to the DB model
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (addresses.includes(jsonResponse[i].address)){
            console.log(jsonResponse[i].address + " --> " +jsonResponse[i].balance)
            testbalance.push({
                address: jsonResponse[i].address,
                balance: Math.round(Number(jsonResponse[i].balance))
            })
        }
    }
    //uploads the data
    function saveBalance(){
        return new Promise ((resolve) => Balance.create(testbalance,function(err) { 
            if (err);
            resolve();
        }))
    }
    //sends the data
    async function sendData(){
        const data = await saveBalance(); //waits for saveBalance resolution
        //sends the data to the tgBot
        Balance.find({}, function(err, data){
            bot.sendMessage(groupId, JSON.stringify(data)) 
          });
    }

    sendData();
```